# Sail & Rail to from Ireland to the Isle of Man

Tags: trains, ferries, ireland, isle-of-man

I've often used Sail&Rail tickets to travel between Ireland and the UK. Seat61 tells me that Sail&Rail is also available [from the UK to the Isle of Man](http://seat61.com/Isle-of-Man.htm). However, I cannot find out whether I can use Sail&Rail between Ireland and the Isle of Man. (Tickets from the Republic of Ireland or Northern Ireland would do.)

The Seat61 site has an embedded booking form from [Rail Easy](http://new.raileasy.co.uk/), but that just says "No journey found".

Comment: Yeah I looked into it a while back and also ran into the same problem with Seat61's booking :/  Alas I never did the trip.

Comment: Bahn.de finds me connections from Tullamore via Holyhead and Liverpool. I'm sure there are direct ships from Dublin to Douglas. I'm guessing those ferries aren't in the rail booking system.

Comment: I checked it out in June 2015, for dates in June and July, Dublin as well as Belfast, no results found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well one reason why this is not in the rail booking system is probably due to the very few scheduled ferries between Ireland and Isle of Man.

According to [Steam Packet Company](http://www.steam-packet.com/Timetables), there are 2 round-trip possible in the next 6 months, around Christmas.

Bahn.de/OBB do not give any schedule after December 8, 2012 so it would not be included. RailEasy just gives a basic "schedule not found", and loco2 does not know Douglas anyway.

So the best option is to just book a ferry and a train separately (is Rail&Sail a cheaper combined ticket?). Steam Packet Company has [a page with Sail&Rail offers](http://www.steam-packet.com/SailandRail) that does not refer to trips to Ireland.

Comment: In answer to your question, yes, Sail&Rail is a *much* cheaper combined ticket. I once travelled from Hull via Holyhead and Dublin to Tullamore. On the train, I met a guy travelling from Chester to Dublin. He'd bought two separate tickets, and had paid a fair bit more than I had.